# Eclipse Debugger how to skip ClassLoader.class?

Tags: java, debugging, classloader

I wanted to debug my code and I do want to not go into the Classloader. Class when I debug the code. For instance, when I want to step into a constructor I have to go into the classloader.class, instead of going into the class where I defined the constructor.

I did some changes in the preferences. Changed the Step Filtering options and hoped to produce a change, yet nothing happened really.

[image]

How to not get step into the Classloader.Class with the debugger?

Comment: Good to look: http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2011/06/29/skip-over-certain-classes-when-using-step-into-in-eclipses-debugger/

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. Do you know which step filter option to add? You can see the picture for the ones I included, which includes the classloader class.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see that image

Comment: I changed the link and made it public does it work now ?

Comment: Nope. Could you please attach the screen with the question.

Comment: Changed the post !

Comment: you have added `java.lang.ClassLoader` already in the Step Filtering. Ideally this should work